# how to toggle elements in and out of dom when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a button that when I click on it an element is added to the Dom, when I click at it again it is removed. I would like to toggle between these two states. The current code I have only adds and element but does not remove it from the DOM.

Here is the HTML of the home page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div class="container">
        <button id="button" onclick="myFunc()">Hello world</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The css

```
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color:transparent;
    color: black;
}
.para{
    background-color:#196997;
    color: white;
}
/* button:hover{
    background-color:#196997;
    color: white;
} */
.new{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.news{
    display: none;
}
```

and the javascript

```
function myFunc() { 
    var button = document.getElementById('button')
    

    const query = button.classList.toggle("para"); 
    if(query) {
        const body = document.getElementById('body')
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
        newdiv.classList.add('new')
        body.appendChild(newdiv)
    } else {
        body.removeChild(newdiv)
    }
}
```

I would like that when the button is clicked and turns blue, the element is created and when clicked again and button turns white the element is removed. Any tips to handle this and improvement on code will be appreciated. Thanks. Here is the fiddle to observe the code in action.[The code fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camindo/tv1ze5rs/2/)

Comment: May I ask why you need/want to add and remove an element to, and from, the DOM instead of simply toggling between hidden and visible?

Comment: I wanted to create a small application with four buttons, that when I click one button options related to that button is shown and then when I click another button options of that button will appear and the previous removed.  I am doing it this way so that I can be forced to work with arrays in a future problem related to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the created element in a variable outside the function. Then, you can directly call [`Element#remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) when necessary.

```js
let elem;
function myFunc() { 
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    const query = button.classList.toggle('para'); 
    if (query) {
        elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.classList.add('new');
        document.body.append(elem);
    } else {
        elem.remove();
    }
}
```

Note, however, that it is simpler to toggle the visibility of the element with a class instead of adding and removing it from the DOM.